# "Furniture" or "Furnishing" or "furnishings"?

Tags: word-choice

What's the best option in the following case?

> The place had no furniture/furnishing/furnishings, no beds, no decor,
>   nor appliances of any kind.

Comment: Yeah, one of them will do. Which one you use depends on what the place was like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furnishings is the more inclusive answer, as furnishing would include rugs, carpet, window and door treatments. "No furnishing" might take the singular, but the more common usage would be of the plural.  "Furnishings" is better than furniture, because a room without chairs and tables (furniture) could still have drapes and floor treatments (furnishings).